# What does pip install <dot> mean?

Tags: pip

I am installing this https://github.com/wkentaro/pytorch-fcn. It tells me to do this instruction.

```
git clone https://github.com/wkentaro/pytorch-fcn.git
cd pytorch-fcn
pip install .
```

What does `pip install .` mean ? Which folder or file am i running by just typing dot ? `setup.py` ?

Comment: As a more general answer, `.` in both Unix and Windows means "the current directory".

Comment: `pip` displays a page of help text, which tells you that `pip install --help` will give you help text specific to `pip install`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically you are specifying the location from which the `pip` package manager to extract the package information from.
E.g.:

```
# Get the Source code
git clone https://github.com/wkentaro/pytorch-fcn.git

# Change into the cloned git repository:pytorch-fcn
cd pytorch-fcn

# Install the package definitions from current location i.e. pytorch-fcn.
pip install .
```

Here is a brief description:
`pip` executes the `setup.py` which loads the `requirements.txt` which has textual representation of the dependency packages.

**References:**

1. Available [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip/) is the official documentation of `pip`.
2. For better python development workflow refer [here](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/) for why you should use `pip` and `virtualenv`.

Comment: Hello thanks for the reply. I have only used pip to do installations and have no idea how it works. What do you mean by package definitions ? Is there a specific file in pytorch-fcn that pip executes ?

Comment: @kong updated the answer.